# Use an outer function for each row in a dataframe

Tags: r, function, loops, apply, outer-join

I have a question regarding the application of an outer function to every row in a dataframe. I have a dataframe that organises observations of parasites in different bird hosts and I'm trying to compare genetic distances between birds that are used by two different parasites. The data looks like this:

```
> str(NCHaem.dat)
'data.frame':   13 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ Node      : Factor w/ 13 levels "1","2a","2b",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Support   : num  1 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.5 1 1 0.92 1 1 ...
 $ Host1     : Factor w/ 5 levels "Myzomela_cardinalis",..: 2 3 3 3 3 3 1 5 5      
 4 ...
 $ Host2     : Factor w/ 5 levels "Myzomela_caledonica",..: 3 1 2 1 2 1 1 4 4 
 5 ...
 $ Paras1    : Factor w/ 8 levels "BARHON03","MYZCAL03",..: 4 1 1 1 2 2 3 8 8    
 5 ...
 $ Paras2    : Factor w/ 8 levels "MYZCAL01","MYZCAL03",..: 5 2 3 1 3 1 1 6 4 
 4 ...
 $ Paras1Prev: int  1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 14 ...
 $ Paras2Prev: int  1 2 2 5 2 5 5 14 8 8 ...
 $ list.Host1:List of 13
 ..$ : chr  "Philemon_diemenensis" "Zosterops_lateralis" "Myzomela_cardinalis"
 ..$ : chr "Phylidonyris_undulatus"
 ..$ : chr "Phylidonyris_undulatus"
 ..$ : chr "Phylidonyris_undulatus"
```

etc...

I wrote an outer function to calculate all possible genetic distances between birds, which are listed in the list.Host1 and list.Host2 columns (i.e. I have two columns that are listed variables, each of which contains a list of all bird observations for a particular parasite).

To calculate genetic distances between each combination of species in two columns in a single row (row 1 in this case), I have written:

```
testFunc3 <- function(x, y) 
cophenetic.phylo(bird.tree)[as.character(x),as.character(y)]

BirdDistance<-     
  as.vector(outer(NCHaem.dat$list.Host1[[1]],NCHaem.dat$list.Host2[[1]],
  Vectorize(testFunc3)))
> BirdDistance
[1]   0.00000 109.71161  64.76033
```

What I want to do is apply this function to each row in the dataframe and then save the resulting vector into a new column. The problem I have is I can't figure out how to use a for loop or apply to get R to repeat this function for each row in the dataframe. I have tried a for loop, but have had no success:

```
loop<-for(i in 1:nrow(NCHaem.dat)) {
row <- NCHaem.dat[i,]

    outer(NCHaem.dat$list.Host1[[i]],NCHaem.dat$list.Host2[[i]],Vectorize(testFunc3))
}
loop
NULL
```

Any tips would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: could you provide a minimal example of your data and the desired output?